# Load denied by X-Frame-Options does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: php, iframe

I tried to load my site's url 'http://dev.avanixtech.com/machform/trm/embed.php?id=369376' in an iframe. I got this error. "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://dev.avanixtech.com/machform/trm/embed.php?id=369376 does not permit cross-origin framing.". I tried to set "header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); ". But still response header contains 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN'. The same in my localhost working correctly and there is no 'X-Frame-Options' header set to it.

Comment: It looks like you are using an Apache Server. Could that be inserting it automatically ? Check in your Apache httpd.conf if this line is present "Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN"

Comment: Yes I am using apache server. But the other websites hosted in the same can be included in iframe